# I got an error message relative to Autolayout when i want to display the Google+ share dialog

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus

I followed this tutorial to integrate google+ to my iOS app.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/media

I use sign-in button (it works) but after i want to share a picture, i use this code :

```
    -(IBAction) clickOnButtonShare
    {

        id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

        // Set any prefilled text that you might want to suggest
        [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Message aaaaaaaaaaaa"];

        [shareBuilder open];

    }
```

But when i click on my button i got this error :

```
     *** Assertion failure in -[GPPDialogView layoutSublayersOfLayer:],      /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2839.5/UIView.m:8335
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. GPPDialogView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: You are using AutoLayout on your viewController thats holding your share button?

Comment: I got the same error if i check Autolayout or not in the ViewController which hold my share button :(

Comment: @JeanFrançoisManatane have you found a solution to this? I have used auto layout a couple of times (so I felt pretty confident) but I am getting the same error you are getting.